# Why can't I use imap to read email messages multiple times?

Tags: node.js, typescript, imap

I have the following node/typescript process running on Mac.

```
ip-192-168-1-3:~ reza.razavipour$ uname -a
Darwin ip-192-168-1-3.us-west-2.compute.internal 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jan 23 06:52:12 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
ip-192-168-1-3:~ reza.razavipour$ node -v
v12.14.0
ip-192-168-1-3:~ reza.razavipour$ npm -v
"imap": "^0.8.19"
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
```

I have a node server that is supposed to read emails, it is called from a specific route. Nothing fancy.

The following code is in a ts file and it exports one function namely

```
export const connect = () => {
    imap.connect()
}
```

first time i call this function, all is well, I connect I read the specific email and no issues.

Next time I call the exported function nothing happens.
Is there a clean up that i am not doing or what am I missing?

```
const Imap = require('imap');

const MailParser = require('mailparser').MailParser;
import { logger } from '../util/logger';

    var imap = new Imap({
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pw',
            host: 'host',
            port: 32,
            tls: true,
            tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
        }
    );
    
    function openInbox(cb) {
        imap.openBox('INBOX', false, cb);
    }
    
    function processMessage(msg, seq) {
        logger.debug('Processing msg #' + seq);
    
        const parser = new MailParser();
        parser.on('data', data => {
            if (data.type === 'attachment') {
                console.log(data.filename);
                // data.content.pipe(process.stdout);
                data.content.on('end', () => data.release());
            }
        });
    
        msg.on('body', stream => {
            stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                parser.write(chunk.toString('utf8'));
            });
        });
        msg.once('end', () => {
            logger.debug('Finished msg #' + seq);
            parser.end();
        });
    }
    
    imap.once('ready', function() {
        openInbox((err, box) => {
            try {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err);
                    imap.end();
                    return;
                }
    
                imap.search(['ALL', ['SUBJECT', '32']], (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(err);
                        imap.end();
                        return;
                    }
    
                    if (!results || !results.length) {
                        logger.error('No unread mails');
                        imap.end();
                        return;
                    }
    
                    var f = imap.fetch(results, {bodies: ''});
                    results.forEach(result => {
                        const f = imap.fetch(result, {bodies: ''});
                        f.on('message', processMessage);
                        f.once('error', (err) => {
                            logger.error('Fetch error: ' + err);
                        });
                        f.once('end', () => {
                            logger.debug('Done fetching all unseen messages.');
                            imap.end();
                        });
                    });
                });
            } catch (e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        });
    });
    
    imap.once('error', (err) => {
        logger.error(err);
    });
    
    imap.once('end', () => {
        logger.debug('Connection ended');
    });
    
    export const connect = () => {
        imap.connect()
    }
```

Comment: I would say it's reading unread messages, so if you read it the first time it will be skipped the second time. Try marking it as unread to see if it will be read again.

Comment: no it never goes through that code path at all.

Answer (score 0):

it turns, at least in my experimentation, once an Imap instance is connected and ended, it can not be used for follow on connection activities.

Only change I made was to create a new Imap object and use it for the next connection.